# Self Running iterable state machine with Enums in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, enum, state-machine

During development I needed to design a state machine with decision which runs to completion and performs state transition without the need to wait for events. So i come up with the following implementation that I want to share.

So the state machine is described with the following Enum

```
public enum PnoBarringState {
  OPERATOR_WHITE_LIST_START {
    @Override
    public PnoBarringState nextState(SessionData sessionData, String pnoValue) {
        if (commonMethods.isMatchingOperatorsWhiteList(sessionData, pnoValue)) {
            return GROUP_WHITE_LIST;
        } else {
            return OPERATOR_BLACK_LIST;
        }
    }
  },
  GROUP_WHITE_LIST {
    @Override
    public PnoBarringState nextState(SessionData sessionData, String pnoValue) {
        if (commonMethods.isMatchingGroupsWhiteList(sessionData, pnoValue)) {
            return PNO_CHECK_FINISHED;
        } else {
            return GROUP_BLACK_LIST;
        }
    }
  },
  OPERATOR_BLACK_LIST {
    @Override
    public PnoBarringState nextState(SessionData sessionData, String pnoValue) {
        if (commonMethods.isMatchingOperatorsBlackList(sessionData, pnoValue)) {
            return PNO_FORBIDDEN_NUMBER_OPERATOR_LEVEL;
        } else {
            return GROUP_WHITE_LIST;
        }
    }
  },
  GROUP_BLACK_LIST {
    @Override
    public PnoBarringState nextState(SessionData sessionData, String pnoValue) {
        if (commonMethods.isMatchingGroupsBlackList(sessionData, pnoValue))
            return PNO_FORBIDDEN_NUMBER_GROUP_LEVEL;
        else {
            return PNO_CHECK_FINISHED;
        }
    }
  },
  PNO_CHECK_FINISHED {
    @Override
    public PnoBarringState nextState(SessionData sessionData, String pnoValue) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return false;
    }
  },
  PNO_FORBIDDEN_NUMBER_OPERATOR_LEVEL {
    @Override
    public PnoBarringState nextState(SessionData sessionData, String pnoValue) {
        throw new CustomUncheckedException( "Operator Level Barring");
    }
  },
  PNO_FORBIDDEN_NUMBER_GROUP_LEVEL {
    @Override
    public PnoBarringState nextState(SessionData sessionData, String pnoValue) {
        throw new CustomUncheckedException("Group Level Barring");
    }
  };

  public abstract PnoBarringState nextState(SessionData sessionData, String pnoValue);

  public boolean hasNext() { return true; }
}
```

Function "nextState()" is abstract and implemented in each state in order to examine the transition and return to a new state. Only the "END" state is returning to the same state.
Since it is also desinged to be used in a run-to-completation a "hasNext()" function is provided. The "END" state is overwritting so as to declare the finish of the state-machine.

This enum is then used inside a normal application code with the following way.

```
PnoBarringState pnoBarringState = PnoBarringState.OPERATOR_WHITE_LIST_START;

while (pnoBarringState.hasNext()) {
    pnoBarringState = pnoBarringState.nextState(sessionData, pnoValue);
}
```

I am not sure whether any pattern describes it in the same way but i was feeling like sharing it.
Any other approaches are considered valuable.

Comment: There are way better OO [_design-patterns_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state) than this. Use _Flyweights_ instead of the enum.

Comment: To be honest I don't get how with Flyweights will create a run-to-completion case. I mean an single event trigger will cause the pass from all affected states.  Are you also referring that the states will be Different Concrete classes (which is somethign i am trying to avoid)?

Comment: _"which is somethign i am trying to avoid"_ Why so? Usually you should avoid to clutter the context with the concrete states, and especially with their specific behaviors.

Comment: At least i am trying to avoid to depict every state with a class. State Pattern for example creates too many useless classes.  Anyway ... Do you have any small sampe how Flyweights migth help to create a "state or transition pattern since I have never seen any implementation for such a thing.

Comment: Please explain why you feel that the classes created in the state-pattern are useless.

Comment: @MakisPapapanagiotou _"Do you have any small sampe how Flyweights"_ These would be the concrete state classes. You can provide an abstract base class for those which implement no specific behavior, beyond `getNext()`. I have an example for a framework in c++, but it uses templates. I believe with Java generics it could be even easier to implement such.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen: For me the most common problem issue is: More difficult to see all states and their relations by looking at code, since they are spread among several different classes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Can you ping me this part in C++ ?

Comment: sorry ...i mean send me any kind of link to this code..

Comment: @MakisPapapanagiotou https://makulik.github.io/sttcl/ Warning: It's complex, but reasonably documented. And you won't need static polymorphism (it's not possible in Java anyways, and is an optimization for low resource (embedded) systems).

Comment: From a fast look i had this is more like a state-machine pattern. At least one think that mess me up with this is that i don't have a direct look of the state machine interraction. Thus when having multiple and large number of states/events I would rather go towards "transition pattern like". i..e table clearly defining the transitions and having as elements callbacks, function pointers or objects (what ever fits better) to describe the action. Anyway this is a matter of taste and in any case what ever discussion for design principles may give some food for thought (my personal view of course)

Comment: @MakisPapapanagiotou That's where the Java package structure comes in. How I see it is that you now have several different responsibilities stuck in a single enumeration, violating SOLID principles. Also, I have a principle of avoiding introducing non-standard methods to enums. I do not want to surprise my user base with non-standard functionality.

Comment: In a equally valid justification: stuffing the states inside the emum makes it harder to see all states because you always have to open the enum instead of just looking at the class structure.

Comment: Your forbidden values throw when you call `nextState`.  Does it really make sense for `hasNext` to return `true` in this scenario?

Comment: Do your `isMatching...` functions mutate `SessionData`?